# como puedo enviar en el redireccionador &hola=0 con el método post

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando envie datos en post tambien envie en el direccionador de búsqueda algo así: ?view=buscarW&hola=0

Aqui Esta mi codigo:

```
<form action="?view=buscarW" role="search" method="POST">
                <div class="divSearch">   
                    <input type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar sobre la programación Web" required>
                    <a href="&categoria=0" style="display: none;"></a> 
                </div>
                <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa un input del tipo hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hola" value="0">
```

Espero te sirva